# Android 4.4 WebView cannot load "content://" urls in html page

Tags: android, android-webview

This affects also "file:///android_asset/" paths and probably affects only remote domain -> local files requests.

When loading file:///android_asset/index.html with images in the same location, it works fine. When loading URL from external domain and requesting local resource, it does not work.

Comment: Any logs? Do you have INTERNET permission already?

Comment: yup all is working well up to 4.3 but not working into 4.4.

Comment: KitKat 4.4 has some changes regarding WebView.
Check its API: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the 4.4 WebView does not support loading content:// from a remote URL for security reasons.